# How do I see if a class has an init block using reflection?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-reflect

If I have a Kotlin class like the following:

```
data class Foo(
    val count: AtomicInteger
) {
    init {
        count.incrementAndGet()
    }
}
```

How do I determine that this class has an init block using reflection?

The init block does not appear in `Foo::class.members` and I can't see a way of determining it from `Foo::class.constructors`.

Is there any way to find out information about the init block using `kotlin.reflect`?

Comment: I highly doubt this information is available after compilation. Init blocks and property initializers on JVM are compiled into some mixture of constructors and/or field initializers. It’s up to the compiler how it wants to do this in an optimal way.

Comment: @Tenfour04 thanks, I was hoping it would be somehow available in the Kotlin metadata and accessible using reflection but no luck so far

Comment: why do you need it?

Comment: @IR42 dealing with a legacy system that still uses Gson and can't be migrated any time soon :/ When Gson constructs an instance it doesn't run the init block, so I wanted to catch this somehow.

Comment: Does Gson call a constructor? If so, then that will include anything needed in `init` blocks too. (Or if not, then that's probably the larger problem.)

Comment: @gidds unfortunately Gson uses unsafe calls to construct the instance, so it is indeed a larger problem.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I believe your comment is correct, if you change it into an answer I will accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This information is not available after compilation.

Init blocks and property initializers on JVM are compiled into some mixture of constructors and/or field initializers. It’s up to the compiler how it wants to do this in an optimal way.

<sub>Answer courtesy of [Tenfour04](https://stackoverflow.com/users/506796/tenfour04)</sub>